# Haskell insert in data structure

Tags: haskell, data-structures, insert

I'm having issues coding a function in my data structure that receives two strings (A and B) and a structure (C).

The purpose is to create a new structure B and insert it into a structure A, that belongs to, or is, the given structure C.

So, it should look for a structure "named" A in structure C (if there are more "A"'s it should choose the "oldest") and then, if found, create and add a new structure B to the structure "named" A. If not found it should do nothing.

```
data Structure = Structure String [Structure]  

instance Show Familia where
show (Familia a (xs)) = intercalate "\n" $ a : ["  " ++ show x | x <- xs]

insert :: String -> String -> Structure -> Structure
```

I have been coding this:

```
newStrct :: String -> Structure
newStrct a = Structure a []

name :: Structure -> String
name (Structure a xs) = a

StrctList :: Structure -> [String]
StrctList (Structure a []) = []
StrctList (Structure a xs) = [nome x | x <- xs]

search :: String -> Structure -> Structure
search (Structure b xs) = case (elemIndex a (StrctList (Struture b xs))) of  
    Just n -> xs !! n
    Nothing -> Structure "Not found" []

addToStrct :: String -> Structure -> Structure
addToStrct a (Structure b xs) = Structure b ((newStrct a):xs)

insert :: String -> String -> Structure -> Structure
insert a b (Structure c xs) 
    | a == c = addToStrct b (Structure c xs)
    | search a (Structure c xs) /= newStrct "Not found" = addToStrct b (search a (Structure c xs))
```

The issues are the following:
Let's assume I have this Structure

```
J
  K
  L
```

The first issue is that when I want to insert a new structure "M" to the structure "K", it outputs this

```
K
  M
```

Instead of this

```
J
  K
    M
  L
```

And the second is that I don't know how to run all the lists of all the Structures in my main Structure in the attempt to find the designated Structure.

Any ideas? I hope its more clear now. Thanks

Comment: Also, what if there are more than one matches?

Comment: Im sorry for the amateur error, I hope its more clear now @4castle

Comment: It should choose the "oldest", I'm sorry I haven't clarified that earlier @karakfa

Answer (score 1):

Your terminology is a bit vague, but you say you want to "insert" one structure into another. In Haskell, this is impossible; you cannot modify structures, only create new ones. The way to do this in Haskell would be to make a new structure that is the same as the previous structure, but with one new item in it. As your question is a little vague, it's a little hard to figure out if this solves your issue, but I think it's a good place to start.

```
addStructure :: Structure -> Structure -> Structure
addStructure (Structure str ls) struct = Structure str (struct:ls)

emptyStructure :: String -> Structure
emptyStructure str = Structure str []

insert :: String -> String -> Structure -> Structure
insert s1 s2 struct = addStructure struct $ addStructure (emptyStructure s1) $ emptyStructure s2
```

Comment: I have edited the post, I hope its easier to undestand. Thanks anyway!